# How to use 2 or more threads for count a words in a file

Tags: c++, string, multithreading, count, chunks

I wanna make a program which count a words from file in multiple threads, but my program can count it only in one thread, i want to count this more than one thread (and theoretically make my program work faster (file would have much words))
When i input a 1 chunkSize all good, but if i input a 2 or more i have a error

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
std::mutex text_mutex;

int countWords(const std::string& str) {
std::stringstream ss(str);
std::string word;
int count = 0;

while (ss >> word) {
    count++;
}

return count;
}

int countWordsInChunks(const std::vector<std::string> &chunks) {
int totalWords = 0;

for (size_t i = 0; i < chunks.size(); i++) {
    totalWords += countWords(chunks[i]);
}

return totalWords;
}

int main()
{
char pat[100];
unsigned long long res{ 0 };
std::cin >> pat;


std::ifstream fin(pat);
if (!fin.is_open()) {
    std::cerr << "Error opening file." << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

std::vector<std::string> textSplit;
for(std::string line;std::getline(fin,line);textSplit.push_back(line));

std::cout << "Enter a chunk size ";
size_t chunkSize{};
std::cin >> chunkSize;

size_t totalLength{ textSplit.size() };
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> chunks;


std::thread t1([&]() {
    text_mutex.lock();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < totalLength; i += chunkSize) {
        std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator start = textSplit.begin() + i;
        std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator end = textSplit.begin() + std::min(i + chunkSize, totalLength);

        std::vector<std::string> chunk(start, end);
        chunks.push_back(chunk);
    }
    text_mutex.unlock();
});

std::thread t2([&]() {
    text_mutex.lock();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < chunkSize; i++)  
    {
        res += countWordsInChunks(chunks[i]);
    }
    text_mutex.unlock();
});

t1.join();
t2.join();
std::cout << "\n" << res;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: One of the threads will lock the mutex, then do all its work, release the mutex and exit. The other thread will wait for the mutex to be released, do its work, release the mutex and then exit. Which thread that will be first is a race. In short, there's no parallelism here, the threads are useless.

Comment: First of all you need to make sure that bottleneck is CPU power, not IO. In later case you will only make it slower (due to overhead)

Comment: Also, because of the race of which thread starts first, if `t2` starts first then it will index the vector `chunks` out of bounds.

Comment: If you need to use threads, then perhaps use the producer-consumer pattern.

Comment: Multiple threads (or anything for that matter) reading a file is usually of little value. Even if the file can be chunked up to be distributed among the threads safely, there is still only one file and probably only one hardware path to it. Since File IO is slow, all but one of the threads will pretty much always be waiting, and start-up, shutdown and contention between the threads will probably slow things down more than they speed things up.

Comment: @user4581301 *"Since File IO is slow"* this is not so true these days. Recent high-end mainstream SSDs can read files at the speed of 5 GiB/s. Files can be in an OS cache so it can actually even reach >10 GiB/s (e.g. 13 GiB/s on my Linux). A sequential scalar code cannot reach such a throughput in most cases. In fact, parsing is slow, especially stringstream stuff, not to mention the multiple copies. That being said, optimising the sequential code (so to make it IO-bound) rather than using multiple threads is certainly better suited here.

Comment: You are going about it the wrong way.  The code in thread t1 should be moved to main.  main is then responsible to chunk up the file FIRST, then it should allow the other treads to run.  Ideally, there should be an equal number of threads as there are chunks.  Then, each thread should operate on their specific chunk.